# Julia: Assign and Get Functions

Tags: assign, julia

I would like to be able to assign values to variables in Julia through a simple string loop.

For instance:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4 = 14, 12, 34, 19
letters = "abcd"

for i in 1:4
  val = get("x$i")
  var = letters[i]
  assign(var, val)
end

a
14
```

Note, I choose the function "assign" and "get" because I am used to them in R.

The reason I want to do this is because I have a function which takes multiple arguments which are all evaluated identically and I figured there was no point duplicating code.  Something like:

```
function f(a,b,c,d) 

  if a<0 a==-9999 end
  if b<0 b==-9999 end
  if c<0 c==-9999 end
  if d<0 d==-9999 end

end
```

Of course the functions that I am applying to each is really much longer than a simple recode command.

I guess I could do something like this:

```
function f(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4, p=[a,b,c,d])
    for (i in 1:4)
        if p[i]<0
            p[i]=-9999
        end
    end
    sum(p)
end
```

However, this creates other problems with "set index" which is something I will need to read up more on.  Thanks for your consideration!
Francis

Comment: Out of curiosity, what advantage do you think this will offer over using an array or a dict?

Comment: This kind of thing is *not* recommended. It can be done as the answers show, but it's not a very good idea.

Comment: You should definitely do something like the latter attempt. I fixed it, so that the syntax is correct, and it actually runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your second suggestion for what to do, I figure you might actually want something like this.

```
function f(args...)
    acc = zero(args[1])
    for a in args
        if a < 0
            acc -= 9999
        else
            acc += a
        end
    end
    acc
end
```

Usage is just like

Comment: I like this! The only trick is that I would really have some arguments which take the same values and some which do not but I am pretty sure I can easily modify this code `function f(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4, printout=true); acc = (a,b,c,d); ...`.

Comment: It's hard to get the right solution for your problem, when we are working with toy examples that may or may not have the same solution as your actual problem. Glad if I was able to help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4 = 14, 12, 34, 19
letters = "abcd"

for i  in 1:4
    assignment = parse("$(letters[i]) = x$(i)")
    eval(assignment)
end
```

You can read about the `parse` function, which turns strings into expressions, here:
http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.parse

Comment: Edited the question to provide more motivation.

Answer (score 0):

To do this kind of weird dynamic variable trixing in Julia, you have to use macros and metaprogramming. The gist of it is a very powerful interface to code generation. I think it would be possible to write a macro that does the same as the above code on the form

```
x1, x2, x3, x4 = 14, 12, 34, 19
@assign("abcd", 1:4)
```

and translates that "compile time" to

```
x1, x2, x3, x4 = 14, 12, 34, 19
begin
    a = x1
    b = x2
    c = x3
    d = x4
end
```

It will take me some time to write and debug such a macro. Can you describe your use case, so I can see if there are some constraints that are actually not important, or more functionality you'd like? The `1:4` for example seems redundant as I can just use `for (i, letter) in enumerate("abcd")` to get the same loop.